# Magento 2 theme updated with basic functionality

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, theme, custom-theme

At the moment we have always used Ultimo, but it has been discouraged because it has not been updated for almost a year, and it customizes many aspects of Magento that we don't even use.

We, therefore, thought of replacing Ultimo with a lighter theme and having 'Basic' features, such as the possibility to modify the colors, the header, and the footer, and to take care of the responsive.

Unfortunately, all the themes we found were very customized with integrated Page Builder and lots of features in it.

Does anyone know any theme that respects these characteristics or compatible with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not characteristics like this.

The best idea to use Magento luma theme or build a simple theme base on luma.

Every theme has a lot of extensions, which also need to remove.

Best to use luma or build a simple theme base on luma. And customization on this new theme or luma theme.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, it was our second option. However, are there any recommended themes that we can consider?